# EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have one crash file showing crash in my app. I am not able to find out where is the crash point. It seems to be related to core data.
I am using core data to save result while executing. It's not frequent and thus no concrete scenario to reproduce this.

Here is crash log content:

```
    Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
    Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000185d89634
    Triggered by Thread:  0

    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   CoreData                        0x0000000185d89634 0x185d78000 + 71220
    1   CoreData                        0x0000000185dc3314 0x185d78000 + 307988
    2   CoreData                        0x0000000185dbe2ec 0x185d78000 + 287468
    3   CoreData                        0x0000000185db68f0 0x185d78000 + 256240
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186096a4c 0x185fb8000 + 911948
    5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001860939d8 0x185fb8000 + 899544
    6   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186093db8 0x185fb8000 + 900536
    7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185fc10a0 0x185fb8000 + 37024
    8   GraphicsServices                0x000000018f1635a0 0x18f158000 + 46496
    9   UIKit                           0x000000018a8f63bc 0x18a880000 + 484284
    10  GWSApp                          0x00000001001aef7c 0x1000f4000 + 765820
    11  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000196ea6a04 0x196ea4000 + 10756

    Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
    Thread 1:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196fa4c94 0x196fa4000 + 3220
    1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196e8c97c 0x196e7c000 + 67964
    2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196e7f3b0 0x196e7c000 + 13232

    Thread 2 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
    Thread 2:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196fbf498 0x196fa4000 + 111768
    1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018609b8c4 0x185fb8000 + 932036
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019705be7c 0x197058000 + 15996
    3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019705bdd8 0x197058000 + 15832 
    4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197058fac 0x197058000 + 4012

    Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
    Thread 3:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196fa4e7c 0x196fa4000 + 3708
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196fa4cf4 0x196fa4000 + 3316
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186095ecc 0x185fb8000 + 909004
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186093e20 0x185fb8000 + 900640
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185fc10a0 0x185fb8000 + 37024
    5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000185ac64e4 0x185a28000 + 648420
    6   Foundation                      0x0000000186fb1c08 0x186ebc000 + 1006600
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019705be7c 0x197058000 + 15996
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019705bdd8 0x197058000 + 15832
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197058fac 0x197058000 + 4012
```

Any help?

Comment: You have to symbolicate the crash, using the Archive you used when submitting the app.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

@ Droppy, I have symbolicated this and got the problem. Thanks.

I was modifying value of core data entity parameter while processing the same entity parameter. So I solved this problem by creating local variables to store processed data and saving processed result back to parameters.

Comment: For future viewers, please explain what the underlying problem was.

Comment: I was modifying value of core data entity parameter while processing the same entity parameter. So I solved this problem by creating local variables to store processed data and saving processed result bck to parameters.